# Division in PLT Racket

Tags: racket

I'm playing around tonight by writing my own square root function.  I wrote one in Python that uses the `round()` built-in function to stop a loop.  However, I'm rewriting the function in PLT Racket, and am having trouble finding the right function to *round* squares so that I can compare them.

```
#lang racket

(define (mySqrt of)
  (mySqrtWrk 0 of of))

(define (mySqrtWrk minv maxv of)
  (let* ([mid (+ minv (/ (- maxv minv) 2))]
         [squared (* mid mid)])
    (cond
      [(= of squared) mid]     <------ this never evaluates to true
      [(< of squared) (mySqrtWrk minv mid of)]
      [else (mySqrtWrk mid maxv of)])))
```

Can anyone send me to the right documentation page or suggest an alternate solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up `round`, `floor`, `quotient`, and many more in the [Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/).  But note also that Racket (like many other lisps) has a rich numeric tower, with exact rationals etc.

Comment: Ended up using `rationalize` to stop irrational numbers from infinitely expanding.